# How to insert elements in a nested List in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nested-lists

I do not have much experience in Python. 
All I want to do is to insert elements in nested lists.I have two lists which seems to be similar but their behaviour is completely different.

`list1 = [['a','b']] * 3
list2 = [['a','b'],['a','b'],['a','b']]`

When I output print these two lists both give same output: 
`[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]`

But when I try to insert elements in nested lists both do that in a different way. Below is the code for inserting elements in nested list.

```
list1 = [['a','b']] * 3
for item in list1:
  item.append("Hello")
print (list1)
```

This outputs

`[['a', 'b', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello'], ['a', 'b', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello'], ['a', 'b', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello']]`

While when I define list in the following way it does exactly what I want.

```
list2 = [['a','b'],['a','b'],['a','b']]
for item in list2:
  item.append("Hello")
print (list2)
```

This gives following output:
`[['a', 'b', 'Hello'], ['a', 'b', 'Hello'], ['a', 'b', 'Hello']].`

Why are these two behaving differently?
    `list1 = [['a','b']] * 3`
    `list2 = [['a','b'],['a','b'],['a','b']]`
[Screenshot of Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqP5s.png)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `*` operator here, you are saying "I want 3 of these".

So you're getting 3 references to the same `['a', 'b']`. In your case, you're adding `'Hello'` to that same `['a', 'b']` reference.

[List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

If you want to make 3 separate references, try using list comprehension:

```
>>> x = [['a', 'b'] for i in range(0, 3)]
>>> x
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
>>> x[0].append('Hello')
>>> x
[['a', 'b', 'Hello'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: Thanks, So how Do I create a nested list with variable length . Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I would use a list comprehension: `x = [['a', 'b'] for i in range(0, 3)]`. The difference here is that this will create a new `['a', 'b']` each time.

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer in the question asked earlier. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [['a', 'b']] * 3
```

This creates a list of lists, as you know. However, the nested lists are actually all references to the same list object.

So when you iterate over `list1` with

```
for item in list1:
```

`item` refers to the same list object on each iteration. So you repeated append to the same list.

On the other hand, `list2` in your example code is explicitly assigned a list with three different lists. Those lists happen to have the same elements, but they are distinct lists.